# Issues with Pro*C compilation on Suse linux

Tags: linux, proc

Would someone please explain what all environment variables needs to be set prior compiling Pro*C code On Suse Linux.

I have tried setting up Oracle_Home, Path and LD Library path according to the Oracle installation.

My code comprises of multiple make files, around 60+ to be precise, distributed across different folders in located in different locations.

(All the make files are dependent on each other. This is additional info which doesn't have any relevance to the question asked).

When I am trying to compile the code, the make files are exiting with error 40. What I am seeking for is, what all variables needs to be set prior compiling huge volume of pro*C code?  Which folders existence should be in synch (if required). According to my knowledge, I need only Oracle home, LD Library path and Path variables set accordingly, however in my case, I am not able to compile the code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include more specific details about the problems you're facing. How have you set the variables, exactly, etc., what errors you're getting…